# Ruby Fiddle and Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)

Tags: ruby, macos, gil, fiddle

I am using [Fiddle](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/fiddle/rdoc/Fiddle.html) to call an external C Function for some heavy [linear algebra](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/BLAS_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000414-SW1) calculations (Mac OSX).

The module definition looks like

```
  module BLAS
    extend Fiddle::Importer
    dlload $BLAS_PATH
    extern 'void cblas_dgemm(int, int, int, int, int, int, double, double*, int, double*, int, double, double*, int)'
    extern 'void cblas_dgemv(int, int, int, int, double, double*, int, double*, int, double, double*, int)'
.......
```

The libraries have been optimized for mac osx and can use all the cores available. Unfortunately when I call these functions from Ruby with Fiddle only one core is used and my understanding is that this happens because of the `GIL`.

Is there a way to release the lock during the execution of external functions?

I am using `ruby 2.0.0-p247` (not the system Ruby).

Comment: I just noticed that Fiddle releases the gil in ruby 2.3 - if you can update ruby that is probably the easiest solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ruby 2.3 this is the default (see [the issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11607) on the ruby bug tracker).

Prior to that, it doesn't look like it was exposed in the Fiddle api. There is a function in the ruby c API called `rb_thread_call_without_gvl` that does pretty much exactly what it says on the tin: it releases the gvl, calls the passed function, reacquires the gvl and returns. It's a little tricky to use - be sure  to read the comments in [thread.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/thread.c#L1241).

If you can't upgrade, I suspect your best bet is to write a very thin C layer that wraps calls with `rb_thread_call_without_gvl` and then use fiddle to call that wrapper library.